# Iconography for "Paid" and "Pay Later"?

Tags: interface-design

I have been trying to work with using iconography for the status of a booking, which allow my app users to pay now or pay later. After they have selected from these options, they are presented with a list of bookings, which the "Paid" or "Pay Later" details are a part.

As there are more important details displayed on the booking, which need to be visible at a glance, I would like to show the "Paid" and "Pay Later" details as icons (with a touch action revealing the written status).

However, I'm having trouble with the Paid and Paid Later icons? Any Advice? Have you done this in an iOS app interface before?

Comment: What is the minimum icon size?

Comment: At 2x the maximum size is 96px by 96px  (not supporting iPhone 6/plus yet). Supporting low resolution will mean half the size.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

Use color (i.e. a green currency symbol = paid), while a grey icon = not paid

Use "sub-icons", that is have the currency symbol and then offset in the lower right, have a check mark (paid) or a clock-face (pay later).

Comment: Sounds like a good option! The only thing I see with this, and I should have mentioned it in the question; the pat later option is still valid, but the user has parted with money (not on the app anyway) so wouldn't involving currency confuse the user? Convince them they have spent money?

Comment: Does the app handle the payment? Or is there any way to confirm a payment was made? 

My thought with the currency symbol was because I'm not sure what else you would pay a bill with. 

A third option, how about a "pill" that just says "paid" or "unpaid"

Comment: Yeah the app does handle credit card transactions. We thought about using the pill method, but there was just too much text onscreen. What I'm currently using is the sub icon method, we have three icons in total; a check mark (a free booking), a check mark with an inset credit card (paid booking) and finally a set of Dumbbells with an inset dollar bill (the Dumbbells are referenced else where in the app as the Gym locations icon, with the dollar bill indicating a cash payment later. The user will also see this icon when they select the 'Pay Later' option). How does that sound?